# Fundamental representation of data relationships?

Tags: data-structures, information-theory, database-theory, knowledge-representation

This is an offshoot of this question [Which is more fundamental: key-value or subject-predicate-object?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55334/which-is-more-fundamental-key-value-or-subject-predicate-object)

Is there any fundamental, hypothetical or practical, representation of data relationships?

Both Key-Value and Subject-Predicate-Object describe pretty well relationships between data in any format. And any relationship can be reduced to be represented by either of them. Is there any theory behind this?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by fundamental?

Comment: No, I can't. If I could define fundamental in this context I wouldn't need to ask the question because I would already know the fundamental representation (by definition). My question is basically if in the theory of data relationship is there a definition which could be interpreted as fundamental in the context of my question (represent K-V or S-P-O data relationship in a theoretically coherent way that allows to reason about it and draw further conclusions from it - if I can express myself correctly).